ADO recordset returns COUNT field incorrect or syntax error in ASP
I'm receiving the error below once my code reaches rs.Update and I'm not sure why.
It was working on a previous server but the error started after I migrated to a newer site & sql server.
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

<%
session("dsn_name") = "driver={SQL Server};server=server1;database=DB1;User ID=User1; Password=pw;"
DIM updateNPI, keyID, oldNP, newNP
    updateNPI = ""
    keyID = "371"
    oldNP = ""
    newNP = "2324"
    set systemConn = server.CreateObject ("adodb.connection")
    systemConn.ConnectionString = session("dsn_name")
    systemConn.Open
    set rs = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.recordset")
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer
    rs.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    
    sql = "select * " &_
        "from tblMain " &_
        "WHERE MainKey = " & keyID & ""
    
    rs.Open sql,systemconn
    oldNP = rs("NP")
    
    rs("NP") = TRIM(newNP)
    rs.Update
    rs.Requery
            
    rs.Close
    set rs = nothing
    systemConn.Close
    set systemConn = nothing
%>


There is no COUNT field in your query. Where is this error coming from?

What is the source database being used here? Does the table in question have a PK value setup? Also, since your using ado, and not ado.net, then the project should be forced to x32 or x64 bits to match the ado being used here.

@b126 Correct I don't have COUNT so it's very odd. It's telling me the error occurs at rs.Update

I would test for a valid record count (say .recordCount <> 0 then)

Why use a Recordset to begin with? Why not run an update query instead? You are simply updating field NP.

@AlbertD.Kallal Thank you this helped. recordCount returned -1. The issue was that adUseServer is no longer used, now uses adUseClient.

Does this answer your question? Understanding Classic ASP

To use features like RecordCount and editable recordsets you need specific lock and cursor options (which I can't remember off the top of my head but you can google them) and I think you need to use a SQLOLEDB or SQLNCLI connection string rather than an ODBC one.  I recommend using insert/update/delete sql queries rather than editable recordsets though, they work with all databases.
